# Unable to read the selected drop down list value on page load after pressing browser back button

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, ajax, browser

Unable to read the selected drop down list value on page load after pressing browser back button.But this happen only during the first function call.
I'll explain in details:
When a page loads initially i have attached an ajax javascript as shown below

```
this.Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "onload", "_Initialize_Chart();", true);
```

Below is the javascript AJAX function

```
    function _Initialize_Chart() {

    var selectedDeptId = $(ddlQueues).val();
    var selectedMonth = $(ddlMonth).val();
    var selectedYear = $(ddlYear).val();
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: ajaxCallHandlerUrl,
        data: {
            OpCode: "GetCallAverageMonthlyReportForGraph",
            Params: "DeptId^" + selectedDeptId + "~Month^" + selectedMonth + "~Year^" + selectedYear
        },
        dataType: "xml",
        beforeSend: function () {
            $('#' + lblCallAverageDetails).html('');
            document.getElementById(chartdiv).style.backgroundImage = "url('../images/ajax-loader_new_.gif')";
        },
        success: function (responseString) {
            document.getElementById(chartdiv).style.backgroundImage = "";
            _Load_Chart(responseString);
            _Load_CallAverageGridData();
        },
        error: function (xhr, errorType, exception) {
            var errorMessage = exception || xhr.statusText;
            alert("There was an error Initializing Charts :: " + errorMessage);
        }
    });
}


    function _Load_CallAverageGridData() {
    var selectedDeptId = $(ddlQueues).val();
    var selectedMonth = $(ddlMonth).val();
    var selectedYear = $(ddlYear).val();
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: ajaxCallHandlerUrl,
        data: {
            OpCode: "GetCallAverageReportDetail",
            Params: "DeptId^" + selectedDeptId + "~Month^" + selectedMonth + "~Year^" + selectedYear
        },
        dataType: "",
        success: function (responseString) {
            $('#' + lblCallAverageDetails).html(responseString);
        },
        error: function (xhr, errorType, exception) { //Triggered if an error communicating with server  
            var errorMessage = exception || xhr.statusText; //If exception null, then default to xhr.statusText  
            alert("There was an error Fetching Call Average Data :: " + errorMessage);
        }
    });
}
```

So this javascript loads the page content which is a graph and a grid.
On clicking the rows in the Grid, it navigates to another page.
Now on pressing the browser back button,the above shown javascript is initially called but the  `var selectedMonth = $(ddlMonth).val();` doesn't give me the value of the actually selected value in drop down list.
On Success of first Ajax call, another Ajax call `_Load_CallAverageGridData();` is made in which i'm getting the value of `var selectedMonth = $(ddlMonth).val();` correctly.
Can any one throw some light why this is happening.

Answer (score 0):

your code in page load

```
 this.Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "onload", "_Initialize_Chart();", true);
```

is not executed on page load, for it to excecute you need to use url hash function.
for it simply use this

where you click on product/image on page there call onclick javascript function i.e.

```
function getHashOnBack(valueget) 
{
   location.hash = "#backTo=" + $(window).scrollTop();$(document).height();
}
```

Now, put

```
$(document).ready(function () 
{
var ab = window.location.hash.substring(1).split("=");
if (ab[0] == "backTo") 
{
 // this would be called automatically when back putton pressed and hav #back=1234   etc. // value in url

 $(window).scrollTop(parseInt(ab[1]));
}
}
```